# How to modify actionbar menu when slide in viewpager?

Tags: android, menu, android-viewpager

I want to modify actionbar menu when slide to another pager in viewpager, Because different pager has different menus, So I register a page change listener for the viewpager, but I don't know how to modify menu in this listener, firstly Should I get the menu object? and how to get a menu object?

Comment: check 'invalidateOptionsMenu ()', reset your action menu

Comment: You may change menu options by calling onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) method.